# FFmpeg crop .wmv video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, powershell, crop, wmv

I have some **.wmv** files that have black borders around and I would like to crop them. Here's a powershell script I got from web that I'm using to crop **.mp4** files, which it does just beautifully.

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -Filter *.mp4| ForEach-Object {
    $exportPath="..\$($_.Name)"
    #Know where to cut
    $results=ffmpeg -ss 10 -i $($_.Name) -vframes 10 -vf "cropdetect=24:16:0" -f null - 2>&1
    #Cut
    if(($results | ? {$_ -match 'crop=\d[0-9]{1,4}:\d[0-9]{1,4}:\d[0-9]{0,4}:\d[0-9]{0,4}'})){          
        Write-Host "The regular expression was matched, value $($Matches[0])."
        ffmpeg -i $($_.Name) -crf 18 -vf ($Matches[0]) -c:a copy $exportPath
    }else{
        Write-Host "The regular expression was NOT matched. The line was '$($resultsParsed[0])'"
        $results | Out-File .\resultsFromCropDetect.txt
    }
}
```

Needless to say it produces horrible quality for the **.wmv** files cropped with it.

So, my question is what set of commands should I use for lossy or even lossless output?

EDIT:
@Rotem
I used FFprobe,

```
 Stream #0:0: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 192 kb/s
 Stream #0:1: Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 1440x1080, 24000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn
```

I'm using cropdetect because it is really easy to find dimensions and automatically crop the video

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079577/how-to-get-better-quality-converting-mp4-to-wmv-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Note that you could even use ffmpeg to convert the .wmv files to .mp4 or .mkv.

Comment: For the lossless solution, we need to know video codec. `WMV` is the container, and it is not very relevant. The video codec may be H.264 (AVC) or H.265 (HEVC) or VP8 or VP9... Please use a tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or FFprobe, to find the video codec. Use the edit button, and add it to your post. Please change the code sample to work on a single file (not `*.mp4`). Do you really need `cropdetect`, or do you know the size to crop?

Comment: I thought we could use [Bitstream Filters](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html), with crop arguments, but it's not relevant for **wmv3** video codec. I think re-encodding is the only option. The options are described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378548/ffmpeg-crop-a-video-without-losing-the-quality).